# How to get access to this server?

Tags: postgresql, azure-sql-database

I'm a total newbie with data analysis background. Today I was passed on this information as in the image below to remotely get access to a database, which I don't know what app it uses.

Can you take a look and tell me what this is?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) screenshot.

Do This:

1. [Download and install Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=redhat-install%2Credhat-uninstall)
2. [Install PostgreSQL extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/postgres-extension?view=sql-server-ver16)
3. Now, [connect to the PostgreSQL database this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-postgres?view=sql-server-ver16#connect-to-postgresql) and fill up all the fields with the credentials you see on the KeePass:

[image]

You should be able to connect now.